# R: Copying value for one type of group and year downwards and upwards

Tags: r, copy, group

I created a simplified version of my data since my actual data is too large to be include here.

```
structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C"), Category = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L), Cost = c(NA, 
100L, NA, NA, 99L, 45L, 34L, NA, 64L, 34L, NA, 34L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

The focus here is on the column "Cost" . If there is NA, in a first step, I use the most recent year with available data in the respective category.

```
Data %>%
  group_by(`Category`, Year) %>%
  dplyr:: mutate(Cost = na.locf(Cost))
```

The problem now is that for "Name" A, there is no value in the "Year" 2018. That's why I get an error. How do I need to adjust, the code, that then in a second step, if there is no data available from prior year for this respective "Category", I use the data from the next available year. In this specific case it would be "Year" 2019 and the value 100.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tidyr::fill` with `.direction = "downup"`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Data %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  fill(Cost, .direction = "downup")

# A tibble: 12 × 4
# Groups:   Category [2]
   Name  Category  Year  Cost
   <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
 1 A            1  2018   100
 2 A            1  2019   100
 3 A            1  2020   100
 4 A            1  2021   100
 5 B            2  2018    99
 6 B            2  2019    45
 7 B            2  2020    34
 8 B            2  2021    34
 9 C            2  2018    64
10 C            2  2019    34
11 C            2  2020    34
12 C            2  2021    34
```

Comment: Ok, great thank you Maël!! What do I need to do with the code in case I want to assign a the specific value for "Cost", e.g., here 100 from "Year" 2019 for  "Name" A directly to Year 2018?

Comment: Use `replace`:  `Data %>% 
  mutate(Cost = replace(Cost, Year == 2018 & Name == "A", Cost[Year == 2019 & Name == "A"]))`

Comment: One additional question: Do you know why your code in the answer does not work when I use group_by(Category, Year) instead of only group_by(Category)?

Comment: Yes because when you group you apply fill only within group. Your groups are only 1 row if you had year